# Terminated Users script - adapt single-run script to run for multiple users?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I don't want to run script for each terminated user, I assume I need to use do `while` loop for this so the it will continually loop over and over again until the `ESC` option.

I have been trying to do this in powershell, but I am new to it and am still learning. Do you have any idea?

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Please enter in your Domain Admin credentials.  Please remember it should be in the form of DOMAIN\username.",0,"Credentials Needed!",0x0)   
$creds = Get-Credential
 $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"*-AD*:Credential"=$creds}

#Here we create the connection to the exchange server. Edit with your mailserver info
$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://**editmemithyourwebmailservername**/PowerShell
Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Terminated Employee Process Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.MaximizeBox = $False


$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$userinput=$UserTextBox.Text;$forwardemail=$ForwardingTextBox.Text;$ticketnumber=$TicketTextBox.Text;$disableuser=$DisableUserCheckbox.Checked;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 
#$objForm.Font = $Font 
#VERSION NUMBER
$VersionLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$VersionLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,10) 
$VersionLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20) 
$VersionLabel.Font = $Font 
$VersionLabel.Text = "V1"
$objForm.Controls.Add($VersionLabel) 

#OK AND CANCEL BUTTONS
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,320)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$userinput=$UserTextBox.Text;$ticketnumber=$TicketTextBox.Text;$forwardemail=$ForwardingTextBox.Text;$disableuser=$DisableUserCheckbox.Checked;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)


#USERNAME LABEL
$UserLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$UserLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$UserLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$UserLabel.Text = "Username of Terminated Employee"
$objForm.Controls.Add($UserLabel) 
#USERNAME TEXT BOX
$UserTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$UserTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$UserTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($UserTextBox) 

#DISABLE USER CHECKBOX CONTROL
$DisableUserCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$DisableUserCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,30) 
$DisableUserCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,40)
$DisableUserCheckbox.Text = "Disable The User?"
$objForm.Controls.Add($DisableUserCheckbox)

#FORWARD EMAIL LABEL
$FowardEmailLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FowardEmailLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80) 
$FowardEmailLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$FowardEmailLabel.Text = "Forward Email to Manager? If Yes, Type In Email Address"
$objForm.Controls.Add($FowardEmailLabel)

#FORWARD EMAIL TEXT BOX
$ForwardingTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$ForwardingTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100) 
$ForwardingTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,40) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($ForwardingTextBox) 

#ENTER TICKET NUMBER TEXT LABEL
$TicketLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TicketLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) 
$TicketLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$TicketLabel.Text = "Issue Number"
$objForm.Controls.Add($TicketLabel)

$TicketTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TicketTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,170) 
$TicketTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,250) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($TicketTextBox) 


#CANCEL BUTTONS
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,320)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close(); $cancel = $true})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


$objForm.Topmost = $True
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
if ($cancel) {return}
#$OKButton.Add_Click({$userinput=$UserTextBox.Text;$ticketnumber=$TicketTextBox.Text;$forwardemail=$ForwardingTextBox.Text;$disableuser=$DisableUserCheckbox.Checked;$objForm.Close()})
#$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})

#COMMON GLOBAL VARIABLES
$disableusercheckbox=$DisableUserCheckbox.Checked
$userinput=$UserTextBox.Text
$forwardemail=$ForwardingTextBox.Text
$ticketnumber=$TicketTextBox.Text

$Month = Get-Date -format MM
$Day = Get-Date -format dd
$Year = Get-Date -format yyyy




If ($OKButton.Add_Click) {


########
#ACTIVE DIRECTORY ACTIONS
#########

#DISABLE THE USER
If ($disableusercheckbox -eq $true)
{
  Disable-ADAccount -Identity $userinput
  $disabled = $userinput + " has been disabled"
} else { 
    $notdisabled = $userinput + " has not been disabled at this time" 
}

#GETS ALL GROUPS USER WAS PART OF BEFORE BLOWING THEM OUT
    $User = $userinput
    $List=@()
    $Groups = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty memberof
    foreach($i in $Groups){
    $i = ($i -split ',')[0]
    $List += "`r`n" + ($i -creplace 'CN=|}','')
    }

#BLOW OUT GROUPS OF USER EXCEPT DOMAIN USERS
(get-aduser $userinput -properties memberof).memberof|remove-adgroupmember -member $userinput -Confirm:$False

#SETS THE USERS TITLE,COMPANY/MANAGER TO DISABLED
set-aduser -identity $userinput -title "CompanyName - Disabled $Month/$Day/$Year"
set-aduser -identity $userinput -company $null
set-aduser -identity $userinput -manager $null
set-aduser -identity $userinput -department $null
set-aduser -identity $userinput -description "CompanyName - Disabled $Month/$Day/$Year per Issue# $ticketnumber"

#CHANGES THE USERS PASSWORD
$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "G00dBye@1234" -AsPlainText –Force
Set-ADAccountPassword $userinput –NewPassword $newpwd -Reset

#MOVES THE USER TO DISABLED USERS
Get-ADUser -Filter { samAccountName -like $userinput } | Move-ADObject –TargetPath "OU=Disabled Users,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"


#HIDES USER FROM GLOBAL ADDRESS BOOK and configures forwarding
Set-Mailbox -Identity $userinput -ForwardingAddress $forwardemail -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true

#REMOVES THE SESSION
Remove-PSsession $ExchangeSession 

Start-Sleep -s 2

}
```

Comment: There would be several ways of doing this but none of them simple for a beginner. With Forms you could populate a ListView to select from, or as it is now but have an Add button to add to a list. If you want to throw intuition out the window for simplicity you could just have a multiline textbox and comma separate the parameters. As Robin has said you could also throw out forms completely and use a spreadsheet, or even enter it via command line. Regardless, it would require a total rewrite of everything except the "AD Actions" code.

Comment: Thanks. So How can we do it with multiline textbox ? please clarify me.

Comment: That's an answer I'm not really willing to commit the time to. However I can point you at this really cool tutorial for using WPF forms in PowerShell which should point you in the right direction https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Form text boxes are going to be tricky to handle multiple users. So instead, use a CSV file as input file with the username and ticketnumber as headers.

`$CSVList = Import-csv C:\Temp\InputFile.csv`

Use a Foreach loop to loop through each line in the CSV.

```
Foreach ($Line.Username in $CSVList)
{
     #your termination code goes here
     #if at any point you need to use the ticket number for this user

     $TicketNo = $Line.TicketNumber
     #This is the Header you used in the csv file.
}
```

For Display, create an object table (much like a csv file) and show it using a `Datagridview` or the more simpler `Out-Gridview` instead of labels so you can support displaying multiple users. (`Out-Gridview` will create its own window though)